# Need to run SMTP on localhost with October CMS / Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel, smtp, octobercms

I have an instance of October CMS running on my localhost, and I need to send emails to various internal addresses (within the company I work for) via the Mail configuration using **SMTP** Method (as requested by my superior). I had emails working fine using the **PHP Mail** Method with the addition of SSMTP to my system. However, for me to do this I was tunneling emails through my personal Gmail account, and we *certainly don't want to do that!* (By "we" I really mean "I") So, if anyone has any clues as to how I should go about this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: So what are you going to use as a mail server. Do you have one in the company?

Comment: Eventually it's going to its own server here in our location. We have a mail server in the company.

Comment: If it is temporary, simply create another clean gmail account and use those credentials, imo.

Comment: Well if all the recipients are local they should all be on your local mail server, use that and php mail or phpMailer is SMTP is absolutely necessary

Comment: @VinnieSaletto If I understand, you only need a mail server to run with October?

Comment: Yes. To be able to send email out with my client's company name on it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create your email server.

**Windows -> [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com)**

**Others systems (Linux) : there are many options, find your best. [Google it](http://google.com/?q=linux+smtp+server).**

After, foward your port. [Check this website, *many ads*](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/).

Finally, October part. Go to `config/mail.php`. And change your SMTP server setting to yours.

**But, I don't recommand this. Why? Because fowarding port can be dangerous, sometimes.** You also have to turn your computer on if people want to reply you.

Instead, use your compagny mail server and change the setting to your compagny. Simple as that (-:.

Hope this help,

FelixINX